# Passing item Id in the loop to Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am building a 'like' button for each comment and posting data using jQuery to `PostsController`. How can I pass the Id value, `@item.Id`, for each item in the loop? Whats the proper way to handle it in jQuery code?

```html
@foreach (var item in Model.PostComments)
{ 
  <a id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span></a>
 }
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#@item.Id").click(function() {
    var FollowOptions = {};
    FollowOptions.url = "/Posts/CommentUp/";
    FollowOptions.data = { id: "@Model.PostComment.Id" };
    $.ajax(FollowOptions);
  });
});
```

```csharp
public IActionResult CommentUp(Guid id)
{
  PostComment PostComment = _context.PostComment.Where(m => m.Id == id).SingleOrDefault();
  if (PostComment == null)
  {
    return NotFound();
  }

  string currentuserid = _userManager.GetUserId(User);
  if (_context.CommentMetric.Where(f => f.PostCommentId == id && f.ApplicationUserId == currentuserid).Count() == 0)
  {
    _context.CommentMetric.Add(new CommentMetric
    {
      Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
      ApplicationUserId = currentuserid,
      PostCommentId = id,
      VoteValue = 1
    });

    return RedirectToAction("Details/" + id);
  }
```

Comment: Are you only wanting to pass one id to the controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you have currently is that your jQuery code is only being assigned on one `id` from the `Model.PostComments` loop - presumably the last one. You have the same issue in referencing `Model.PostComment.Id`.

It would make more sense to apply a common class to the `a` elements you create in the loop, then read the `id` attribute from that and send it in the request, something like this:

```html
@foreach (var item in Model.PostComments)
{ 
  <a id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-success btn-like" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span></a>
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.btn-like').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: '@Url.Action("CommentUp", "Posts")',
      data: { id: this.id }
    });
  });
});
```

Note the use of `Url.Action()` instead of hard-coding the URL in the example.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer but the <a> tag is not clickable now.

Comment: `a` tags must have an `href` to be clickable. If you don't want it to actually go anywhere just use `href="#"`.

Comment: @ChrisPratt very good point. I updated the answer. I also added a call to `preventDefault()` on the click event to stop the `#` being added to the URL

Comment: Also, the `Id` property on an entity should not be used directly as the `id` attribute on an element. This property will normally be an int, and HTML ids cannot start with a number. You'd instead need to do something like `id="item@(item.Id)"`. In general, it's preferable to use `data-*` attributes for this kind of stuff, i.e. `data-id="@item.Id"`.

Comment: `HTML ids cannot start with a number` that's no longer the case in HTML5. Pretty much any value without whitespace in it is now valid

Comment: Its clickable now, but it doesn't post to controller/action

Comment: Check the console for errors, and also watch the network traffic to see if the request is sent and what the response is. You're not handling any errors, so it could be the server side code is returning a 500.

Comment: Network is not capturing any data when I click, I have tried all previous suggestions.

Comment: Apologies, I just realised the was a mistake in the selector. I've updated the answer

Comment: I am very grateful to  your answer, It solved my problem.TQ

Comment: How to disable each button after its been clicked, also how to increment like counter through Jquery ?

Comment: You should start a new question about those tasks if you're stuggling

Comment: I have posted new question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54367861/how-to-disable-button-after-its-been-clicked-using-jquery