# How to disable button after its been clicked using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, razor

How to disable each button after its been clicked, also how to increment like counter through jQuery?

I am building a 'like' button for each comment and posting data using jQuery to PostsController. I am passing the Id value, @item.Id, for each item in the loop and handling the Id through below jQuery code.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.PostComments)
{ 
    <a id="@item.Id" href="#" class="btn-sm btn-success btn-like"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span></a>
                    <span id="commentcounter">@Model.CommentMetrics.Where(a => a.PostCommentId == item.Id).Sum(a => a.VoteValue)</span>
}
```

and the jQuery code is :

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.btn-like').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
      $('#commentcounter').text(function(i, oldVal) {
        return parseInt(oldVal, 10) - 1;
      })
      $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("CommentUp", "Posts")',
        data: {
          id: this.id
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: remove the `href=`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable button in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122526/disable-button-in-jquery)

Comment: I went through this post, I want to make both hide and toggle back as appear.

Answer (score 1):

**Jquery Documentation**

Attributes vs. Properties:

> The difference between attributes and properties can be important in specific 
>   situations. Before jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method sometimes took property values
>   into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause inconsistent
>   behavior. As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop() method provides a way to explicitly
>   retrieve property values, while .attr() retrieves attributes.

official documentation: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

For your example you need this:

```
 $(this).prop('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `$(this).prop("disabled", true);` to disable the button inside your click handler

**How to increment comment counter**

First if commentcounter is in loop it will get the same id that will produce an error you can do one thing that append `@item.Id` with the commentcounter id to make it unique so it should look like commentcounter12 , commentcounter23 if `@item.Id = 12 or 23` etc for multiple commentcounters now write this code to increment

```
$('commentcounter'+e.target.id).text(parseInt($('commentcounter'+e.target.id).text())+1)
```

Comment: I have used your suggestion and it worked fine but how to increment commentcounter for each item?

Comment: just right $('#commentcounter').text(odVal+1) and please tell me where are you getting the oldvalue ?

Comment: commentcounter is in the loop and its id is changing for each iteration. How to perform such action ?

Comment: Don't use `attr` for "disabled", use `prop`. See [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5874652/215552)

Comment: I have put it like this   <p align="left">
                        <a id="@item.Id" href="#" class="btn-sm btn-success btn-like"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span></a>
                        <span id="@item.Id">@Model.CommentMetrics.Where(a => a.PostCommentId == item.Id).Sum(a => a.VoteValue)</span>
                        <a id="@item.Id" href="#" class="btn-sm btn-default btn-dislike"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span></a>
                    </p> and its not working too, Jquery next comment

Comment: <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {


            $('a.btn-like').click(function (e) {
                             e.preventDefault();
               
                $(e.target.id).text(parseInt($(e.target.id).text()) + 1);
                $(this).prop("disabled", true);
                         $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("CommentUp", "Posts")',
    data: { id: this.id }
    });
    });
    });
    </script>

Comment: Set the id of span like <span id="commentcounter@item.Id"> i was meant to say span id must contain commentcounter but to make it unique concatinate the value of @item.id with it

Comment: I got an error too :  <span id=commentcounter+@item.Id">@Model.CommentMetrics.Where(a => a.PostCommentId == item.Id).Sum(a => a.VoteValue)</span>

Comment: you can not add + in ids try to write it as id="commentcounter@item.Id"

Comment: You should search your syntax by your self here community can only suggest you solutions. I think you are using razor so it will work like that <span id="commentcounter_@(item.id)"> for reference check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759849/how-to-concatenate-the-id-of-the-html-element-using-razor-asp-net-mvc